# Databricks Notebooks - how to know which kernel

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I am using Databricks community edition for running spark workloads . I understand it uses kernels to run the notebooks

1. Is there anyway to identify which kernel the notebooks uses to run ?
2. How exactly the notebook will run behind the scenes( Very little information available) ?

Comment: do you need to get this information programmatically, or just know what version, etc. is running?

Comment: whatever way it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first question, Databricks has a limited number of supported "main" languages - Scala, Python, R, and SQL - you can set them as primary language when creating the notebook. Besides language set on the notebook level, you can use another language for a given cell by using `magics`, like, `%scala`, `%python`, `%r`, `%sql`.  There are also additional magics, for example, `%sh` for execution of the shell code on the driver, `%fs` for working with files on DBFS, etc.  All of this you can find in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#default-language).

Regarding the 2nd question - actual implementation is not public, but it should work similarly to the Spark implementations - `pyspark`, etc.